# Why does Xcode autocomplete fail to work when I alloc/init a variable?

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode4.3

I have a ridiculous problem with Xcode 4.3.2. Whenever I declare a new variable say
`NSMutableDictionary *var = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`, Xcode autocompletes `NSMutableArray` in LHS of the expression but not in RHS.

[image: Xcode Autocomplete issue]

This is irritating obviously. Often causes typos which I have to re-correct going back and certainly hampers the flow. From my experience it doesn't happen in any other situation.

Anyone else ever faced this? Should I raise a bug?

Comment: In your screenshot, an auto completion of NSMutableDictionary would be wrong anyway, because there is no opening square bracket. A better screenshot will stop pedants like me making useless comments.

Comment: It actually does work with Opening square bracket. But I generally use the style where inserting the ending bracket inserts the beginning one automatically.

Comment: How come autocomplete in the the same place works when I use any variable instead of Class Name?

Comment: The autocomplete uses a sort of live compiler check to only show you relevant completions. The right side of an assignment will only show you completions that lead to a variable - a bare class name is not one of those.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I tried couple of other cases too and seems you're right.

Comment: It's pretty much what Danich is saying, so they deserve an accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's because Xcode doesn't know if you want to make some operation with the class and tries to find an appropriate variable. So if you want Xcode to autocomplete your class name in RHS, first write `[]` then start typing inside: `[NS...]`

Comment: So is this specific to when RHS starts with Class Name? Because it autocompletes perfectly on RHS if I send a message to an instance.

Comment: For e.g. in `NSMutableDictionary *var = [someDict copy];`, Xcode autocompletes someDict perfectly fine.

Comment: Seems that this was indeed the right answer. As per @jrturton in the RHS autocomplete shows possible matches that result into a variable. 

As a rule of thumb, one should always enter [] for autocomplete to work for Class Methods.